# I have UK VISA for 10 years mentioned “only valid if accompanied by father or mother.” Now I am 21 year old can I enter UK without parent now..?

Tags: indian-citizens

I have UK VISA Valid for 10 years with a condition  “only valid if accompanied by father or mother.” Now I have attained 21 year of age can I enter UK without parent now..?

Comment: I am pretty sure we already have a question like this and the answer was No, you need a new visa. But I can not find the question right now.